# how to set column type with create-select statement

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am trying to create a table with a select statement and that doesn't require me to set column types. However i need the column `percent` to be a float but what i am getting are 0 and 1s. How do i set that column as a float or decimal?

```
create table C as(
    select a.pid, b.date,
    ((select a.count(cost) where cost > '10')/(select a.count(cost))) AS percent
    from A a join B b
    on a.pid = b.pid
    group by 1,2,3);
```

my output is something like below but i need it the third col to be a float:

```
pid date percent
1   2015-01-01  1
2   2015-04-03  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
create table C as(
    select a.pid, b.date,
    ((select a.count(cost)*1.000 where cost > '10')/(select a.count(cost))) AS percent
from A a join B b
on a.pid = b.pid
group by 1,2,3);
```

Edit: nevermind the above

The following was tested and appears happy as a float.

```
create table i1
(
    h varchar(10),
    g varchar(10)
);
insert i1 (h,g) values ('a','b'),('a','b');

-- drop table c;

create table c (percent float not null) as 
select h,count(*) as percent from i1

describe c;
```